# list and counting repeat letters

Tags: python

I need to receive a string from the user, present it in list so each organ in the list contains [the letter, the number it repeat in a row].

I thought my code is good but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
my_str = raw_input( "Enter a string:" )

j=0
while j<=len(my_str):
    for i in my_str:
        counter=0
        if i==i+1:
            counter +=1
            continue
            print i, counter

        else:
            print i,1
            j+=1
```

output:

```
Enter a string: baaaaab
As list: [['b', 1], ['a', 5], ['b', 1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is drastically different from your code, but a more efficient way of doing this would be to use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools
my_str = raw_input("Enter a string:")
print [[g[0], sum(1 for _ in g[1])] for g in itertools.groupby(my_str)]
```

Comment: As you should. :) This answer is more of a note for others who might come across the question.

Comment: I wouldn't materialize the list, but rather use `sum(1 for _ in g[1])`

Answer (score 1):

HINT: here, i+1 is not what you mean. The python interpreter tells you what's the problem.

HINT: here, in your code, the `print i,counter` line is never executed.

Comment: Look at the conditional leading to that line. Is it ever possible?

Comment: i want it to check if the current organ=the next organ.
I just didnt success

Comment: indeed, but `i` contains a letter, and `i+1` is not the next letter, it tries to add 1 to your letter, therefore python tells you `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects` which means that it doesn't manage to use the `+` operation on a letter and an integer.

Comment: let's try some [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). What do you want to use your `j` variable for ?

Comment: define how namy times the loop run

Comment: indeed, and why did you choose to run the loop `len(my_str)` times ? (and why is `j` not increased at every iteration ?).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Amber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148870/amber) what you need is already provided by the Counter dicionary in the [collections](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module.

```
from collections import Counter
my_str = raw_input( "Enter a string:" )
count = Counter(my_str)
print count.items()
```

The only limitation is that it will count even the special characters. If you want to count only the standard letters, you can refer to the [string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module to obtain a list of the letters ad keep only the one you are interested into:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_letters
my_str = raw_input( "Enter a string:" )
count = Counter(s for s in my_str if s in ascii_letters)
print count.items()
```

Comment: This is my favorite solution for this.

Comment: He's asking how to find _consecutive_ characters in a string. His example is pretty clear: given a string like `'baaaaab'` is expecting an output like `[['b', 1], ['a', 5], ['b', 1]]`. Your solution gives `[('a', 5), ('b', 2)]`.

Answer (score -2):

The below code is similar to your implementation but using set.

```
s = 'abcdeff'
set((i, s.count(i)) for i in s )
```

output:

```
set([('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('e', 1), ('f', 2)])
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired output for `aba`. Furthermore, if they just wanted a raw count of items in the string, it'd be far more efficient to use `collections.Counter` rather than doing duplicate counts for duplicate letters.

Comment: aba does provide the correct solution and my intention in providing the solution was to help the person relate with a code similar to his own.